# Automatic updates being really annoying, Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: apt, updates, snap

Apt: In Software & Updates, I selected to never automatically check for updates. But it still shows the update popup window every now and then.

Snap: I also set snap auto refresh to some time late in the night. But it still sometimes tries to run updates anyway outside of auto update hours.

I will manually run apt and snap updates at the end of the day. I don't wanna be bugged to run updates while I'm in the middle of doing something. And I certainly don't want Firefox to suddenly crash and be borked for the next 2 minutes because snap randomly decided to run updates.

Comment: Hmmm. I use the default settings, which includes letting snapd check for updates four times daily, and have never had problems with Firefox "suddenly crash" due to snapd updates.. Perhaps there is a different issue there.

Comment: While I haven't had the exact issues you describe, I agree that snap updates seem really annoying. I'm tired of the frequent 'Pending update of "yourbrowser" snap. Close the app to avoid disruptions' I would prefer it either act like software driven updates like the browser on Windows, or in conjunction with the apt update. Closing my browser for up to 4:01 to wait for an update or running the snap command from a terminal is not a good user experience.